# Проблема с парсером на Python

Tags: python, парсер

Решил для работы написать бота который будет отсылать мне ежедневно моё расписание на день. Я в этом деле ещё зелёный и у меня возникла проблема: когда подключаю страницу с расписанием, парсер выдаёт мне страницу без самой таблицы с расписанием, т.к. она ещё не сгенерировалась.

Есть ли какой то способ, чтобы дождаться генерации этой таблицы? За дополнительной инфой пишите в комментарии, буду скидывать всё что нужно.

Вот кусок кода:

```
import requests

class Aquasoft(object):

     def schedule_parse(self):
        request_url = "http://aquasoft.dvfx.ru/"
        session = requests.Session()
        params = {
            "login":     "login",    # Изменено
            "password":  "password"
            }
        auth_req = session.post(request_url, params)

        request_url = "http://aquasoft.dvfx.ru/views/customer_record.php"
        schedule_req = session.post(request_url)
        with open("test.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            print(schedule_req.text, file=f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Aquasoft()
    test.schedule_parse()
```

Comment: Вам нужно перехватить Ajax и распарсить

Comment: Не подскажете какой нибудь гайд, как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно включить в браузере режим разработчика (лучше используйте Firefox, там на русском), откройте страницу и посмотрите какой запрос ajax приходит при создании таблицы

Comment: То есть мне нужно найти нужный .js файл и отправить на него запрос? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: вам нужно найти url ajax-запроса и сделать такой же запрос, а потом разобрать его

Comment: Я нашёл файл с ajax запросами, отправил запрос по url этого файла и мне выдало ошибку 405 Not Allowed

Comment: предоставьте логин и пароль

Comment: либо пишите с помощью Selenium Webdriver и используйте неявные ожидания (намного медленнее, работает через браузер)